# how can i call from my website to mobile or landline phones. (in PHP,Flash, ..)

Tags: php, apache-flex, flash, web-services

I wish to call from mywebsite to mobile phone, how do i implement in PHP or Flash.
Is it possible in PHP, flash, or any other technologies.

Answer (score 3):

I'd take a look at Ribbit - http://www.ribbit.com/

I'm not sure exactly what your requirements are but they have an API that will let you make a call from Flash through their system.

They've got both PHP and Flash APIs - http://developer.ribbit.com/

=Ryan ryan@adobe.com

Answer (score 2):

In order to place a call on a phone from a computer, you either need to:

- have a duplex modem installed on the server
- use a service with an API allowing to place calls

The first option in this case is impractical as it would only mean that you would only be able to place one call at the time. (Well, if you have X modems, each with its own line, you'll be able to place X simultaneous calls)

Therefore, you need to connect to a service providing an API to place calls. Such services isn't free and charge per call. Examples: [Skype](https://developer.skype.com/), [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/).

I have no experience with the second option and therefore cannot give you further input on the subject. Do some research and choose a service which fits your needs.

Comment: @McPherrinM: If you are based in the US, sure... But the asker is from India.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to look at an API for VOIP.  There is an API for Skype https://developer.skype.com/ which might be a good solution.  Andrew is right about using a modem, it isn't going to scale very well.